Should I fetch parent resource along with nested resources in one call, fetch them in separate calls, or both (REST API)?
I have an API design question. If I have a resource with nested resources and half the time I need to fetch the parent along with the nested resources from the client, should I use one call to fetch these resources or would it be better (in terms of design) to fetch them in separate calls?
For example, most of the time I need to fetch a Group with its Employees. Would it be better to fetch them in one call or use two different calls (one for Group and another for Employees?
Also, would it be considered a bad practice to conditionally fetch the nested entities from one call with a conditional parameter?
Example:
/group?withEmployees=true (fetch group with employees)

I believe it would be better to call them in separate calls, because you have to call it sometimes, not always. And you will have better api points if you ever have to only call only one of them later

Thanks for the advice! Do you think it would make sense to have one endpoint that fetches only the parent, and another that fetches them both, or is this too redundant?

I believe the best approach is to have an endpoint to fetch the parent, another to fetch the child. But sometimes you may need another approach like having both on one endpoint, you have to find the best suitable one for your problem, but most times an endpoint for each thing is the best approach


I have an API design question. If I have a resource with nested resources and half the time I need to fetch the parent along with the nested resources from the client, should I use one call to fetch these resources or would it be better (in terms of design) to fetch them in separate calls?

As written, this question doesn't make a lot of sense.  That's not your fault: the literature sucks.
The flaw in your question is this: "resources" are not generalizations of entities in your data model; "resources" are generalizations of web pages.
Resources are just things that can be identified by a uniform resource identifier.  We have primary resources (identified typically by an absolute-URI) and we have secondary resources (some "portion or subset" of a primary resource) identified by referencing a primary resource and additional identifying information in the form of a fragment.  Very roughly
/resources?primary
/resources?primary#secondary

Therefore, when you ask about /group?withEmployees=true, what you are really asking about here is a new primary resource, which presumably has a different current representation than an existing /group resource.


most of the time I need to fetch a Group with its Employees. Would it be better to fetch them in one call or use two different calls (one for Group and another for Employees?

So would it be better to have a single resource with a representation that includes all of the information, or should the information be distributed across two (or more) different resources?
Answer: Yes, one of these choices is likely to be at least marginally better than the other.  But which? is going to be answered by analyzing the trade offs involved, and judging which benefits outweigh which costs.
For API that are primarily about providing information to the client (in other words, for API that are very much like websites), you're primarily going to be focused on the same sorts of questions that you would ask when designing a website - do we want the same authorization policy on both pieces of information? Do we want the same caching policy on both pieces of information?  Do we need to be able to be able to discriminate requests for the information in our tracking / logging? and so on.
For API where clients are regularly sending information that would change the representations of the API's resources, then you also need to be thinking about the cache-invalidation implications of your designs.

An example where trade offs matter: in a lot of API, the designers assume that consumers won't ever be pulling data out of cache -- consumers always fetch fresh information from the origin server and act upon that information as soon as it is available.
And that simplifies things considerably - and works great when it turns out that the assumption is valid.
Of course, if your API becomes catastrophically successful, your origin servers get pounded, and maybe then you do want to be able to put a general purpose web caching appliance in front of your servers, and the tradeoffs change on you.  (And there's nothing wrong with that - needing to update your design decisions because you are trying to carry 100x more traffic than your original targets, and want to continue to grow, is a good problem to have.)

Thank you for such an elaborate answer, I learned a lot from it. Also, thank you for being so understanding of my confusion in terms of resource and data representation. The only thing I didn't understand completely is how my caching strategy affects this decision (I'm currently caching the data), I'll do my research on this topic, but if you have a quick clarification I would appreciate it greatly.

HTTP has general purpose caching built into it (RFC 9111) which includes cache-invalidation (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9111.html#name-invalidating-stored-respons).  Pay careful attention when reading sections 3, 4, and 7.

A good approach for this might using the Prefer: translude= header, which is a draft but is in use: https://inadarei.github.io/draft-prefer-transclude/
This lets you say something like:
Prefer: transclude=collection

This works best with a hypermedia format like HAL. This lets you embed resources using the _embedded key in your JSON response. The appearance of this header could cause the parent to be listed in _embedded, but you must also include a Vary header.
Allowing developers to use a secondary method to do this using a ?transclude= query parameter is not uncommon for other HTTP headers.

I will read more about the approach you propose, thanks!
